# Use VL53L0X with STM32 microcontroller

Tags: api, stm32, microcontroller, adafruit, mcu

I couldn't find information regarding integration between **VL53L0X** and **STM32** microcontrollers using a board such as the ones sold by [polulu](https://www.pololu.com/product/2490) or [adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3317). STM provides an API for P-NUCLEO-53L0A1 that is hard and complex to implement on others STM32 microcontrollers. I saw many examples for Raspberry Pi and Arduino but nothing for generic for STM boards. Is there any example code/tutorial that integrates STM32 MCU with VL53L0X?

Answer (score 0):

The [VL53L0X](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3317) is a generic [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) device. There exist almost never any easy complete libraries for integrating such a device into any environment you might want. What you are going to have to do is to read the [datasheet](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/037/547/original/en.DM00279086.pdf) and possibly any other materials provided by [ST](https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/vl53l0x.html) for it and then write your own interfacing code on top of (preferably) the STM32 I2C HAL.